# How to debounce/throttle this object prop method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, throttling, debouncing, tanstack

I'm using this javascript code for `@tanstack/query` IndexedDB persistance [as documented here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/plugins/persistQueryClient#building-a-persister).

I'm having too much `put()` calls and I would like to throttle/debounce them.

How can I do this in the below code?

```
function createIDBPersister(store: UseStore): Persister {
  return {
    async persistClient(client: PersistedClient) {
      // this is called a lot of times!
      console.log('persistClient()');
      
      set("custom-db", client, store);
    },
    async restoreClient() {
      return await get<PersistedClient>("custom-db", store);
    },
    async removeClient() {
      await del("custom-db", store);
    }
  };
}
```

I tried with:

```
function createIDBPersister(store: UseStore): Persister {
  return {
    async persistClient(client: PersistedClient) {
      
      debounce(() => { // import { debounce } from 'lodash-es';
        console.log('persistClient() inside debounce');
        
        set("custom-db", client, store);
      }, 1000)()

    },
    // ...rest
  };
}
```

But this write the same amount of `console.log()` messages of the first one, only a second late.

Comment: throttling/retrying does *not* seem like the right pattern for an in-memory browser. In fact, isn't indexeddb synchronous? Unless 'm misunderstanding what you're doing, it feels like maybe you need to take a step back and look at the causes of your issue a step deeper.

Comment: IndexedDB is not sync. What is going on here is that @tanstack/query is continuously triggering the `persistClient()` after each API call because it needs to write the data to the cache of course. What I need is to debounce that cache writes. Am I wrong?

Comment: I see, so your goal is then not to postpone calls, but provide a buffer so rapid-fire multiple writes to the same key get de-duplicated/last one wins? And am I assuming correct you are experiencing real performance issues, and not hypothetical/theorized ones?

Comment: @Evert yes. Real.

Comment: Does `PersistedClient` have a property that would make it uniquely identifyable?

Comment: I don't know. Does it matter?

Comment: Yes, because unless you comfortable with calls to persistClient that never get stored, you need some way to find out what the last version of a given client is.

Comment: If the requirement is, "I only want 1 call to persistClient per second to succeed" you don't need it though. @buondevid's answer does the job then.

Comment: It sounds like you want some kind of Promise queue. Alternatively, consider adding a shared promise that you immediately insert between calls. `const delay = () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500)); let waiter = delay();` then in your functions, `async myFn() { await waiter; await operationToThrottle(); waiter = delay();} `

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the tanstack, but it looks like it's `persistClient()` getting called too many times, so you can't debounce inside the function that you want to debounce. You have to debounce the call site of `persistClient()`.

So whatever is calling that function, you can do:

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 200){
  let timer;

  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}

const debouncedPersistClient = debounce(() => persistClient());
```

And then use `debouncedPersistClient()` instead of using directly `persistClient()`.

If you can't control the site, then you could do:

```js
function createIDBPersister(store: UseStore): Persister {
  let timer;
  return {
    async persistClient(client: PersistedClient) {
      clearTimeout(timer)
      timer = setTimeout(() => set("custom-db", client, store), 200);
    },
    // ...
  };
}
```

Be aware that both with debouncing and throttling you will lose some `set` calls, I'm not sure that's what you really want.

Comment: I cannot change where persistClient is called.

Comment: Edited my answer after your comment